# In React Native, how to import another stylesheet into current one?

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I'm a novice.
Now i have to managing two or more stylesheet files in my project.

My current stylesheet code:

```
'use strict';
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
var React = require('react-native');
var {StyleSheet,} = React;
import {NavBar, TabBar} from './UiConfig'
import MyComponents from './styles/MyComponents'

const MyStyleTheme = StyleSheet.create({
    middle: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContents: "center"
    },
    NavBar: {
        backgroundColor: NavBar.bgColor //from UiConfig
    }
})

export default MyStyleTheme
```

And the another file:

```
'use strict';
    import { Platform } from 'react-native'
    var React = require('react-native');
    var {StyleSheet,} = React;

    const MyComponents = StyleSheet.create({
        Navigator: {
            ...
            ...
        }
    })

    export default MyComponents
```

So...it's possible to import a primary stylesheet instead of import another one just like CSS @import or not?

```
index.ios.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native'
import MyStyleTheme from '../primaryStyles'

...
...
...

render(){
    return(
        <View style={[MyStyleTheme.middle]}>
            <View style={[MyStyleTheme.MyComponents]}>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...I found a way to solve it:

```
const obj = { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }  

const MyComponents = StyleSheet.create({
    Navigator: {
        ...obj,
        height: 44
    }
})
```